# Firebase authentication - is it possible to call custom code during user creation?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

When using Firebase authentication, is it possible to call custom code when an authentication user is created?

For instance, I want to create tenant related data as and when a new user is created.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Cloud Functions for Firebase Authentication triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events)? You can write custom code that gets triggered whenever a user is created.

```
export const createTenantData = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // ...
});
```

The triggers should be exported by your `functions/index.js` file.

Comment: Definitely also have a look at the new(er) [blocking functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions). Since these run **before** the user is created or signs in, they can reject that creation/sign-in from completing.